# Angular datatables is searching commented/hidden fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I'm using angular-datatables with `<table datatable="ng">` in my tag.

I have a column in which I'm showing different states (Queued, completed, failed) and toggling them using `ng-if`

I want the user to be able to search based on the status, by typing in the search box auto generated by datatable.

However, its showing all of them, and not just the ones visible in `ng-if`. It does not filter out the hidden states (`ng-if` is working fine, I just see one state)

It works if I type garbage. But if I type **Failed** and there is no failed state, it still shows all of them.

I commented out all of them, and the filter still detects them!

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in myArray">
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <!--<div class="label label-success" ng-if="obj.status==0">Downloaded</div>-->
            <!--<div class="label bg-yellow-dark" ng-if="obj.status==1">Queued</div>-->
            <!--<div class="label bg-info-dark" ng-if="obj.status==2">Downloading</div>-->
            <!--<div class="label label-danger" ng-if="obj.status==3">Failed</div>-->
        </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: It's better in my opinion to add pipe to ng-repeat and filter model that you're passing to table in code, rather then modify DOM.

Comment: But the search box is generated by the plugin, so how can I pipe ng-repeat with its ng-model?

Comment: I didn't know that you're using plugin, but anyway, you may add your own search box with something like ng-model='search' and then use it as I said.

Comment: well, that one I already have. But I need to use pagination and the original searchbox is in front of it. I'm not able to put the new one there, so it cannot happen